# How to estimate my position using Wifi Access Point

Tags: android

i'm (newbie) working on android platform 2.1 and i want to estimate my location using WiFi Access Point. 
i tried with GPS_Provider and Network_Provider but i want to estimate it specifically with WiFi AP in Network_Provider and not through Cell towers. 
is there any way to get my location through WiFi AP? if yes then how?

thanks all for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

you can browse http://www.ip2location.com/ and parse the html output...
or use: http://shaddack.twibright.com/projects/ip2loc/
or you can use ip to location database like this: http://www.andrewsellick.com/83/free-ip-to-location-database